# object destructing with paramaters on function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, ecmascript-6

If I have the following ES6 method:

```
function myClothes([first, second, third]) {
  return {
    first: first,
    second: second,
    third: third
  }
}
```

How do I print out "sneakers pants shirt" in my console window? I have tried the following but I am still short of a solution:

```
console.log(myClothes({
  ['first']:'sneakers',
  ['second']:'pants',
  ['third']:'shirt'
}));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, change your function to use object destructuring. Then use a simple `console.log` statement inside the function:

```js
function myClothes({first, second, third}) {
  console.log([first, second, third].join(" "));
  return {
    first: first,
    second: second,
    third: third
  }
}

console.log(myClothes({
  ['first']:'sneakers',
  ['second']:'pants',
  ['third']:'shirt'
}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: @klewis so the object is the `{ first: "sneakers" }` bit, that's returned from your function. With the `console.log` of the `[first, second, third]`, did you want them joined by spaces like `sneakers pants shirt`?

Comment: @klewis I've edited my answer, does it work for you now?

Comment: ahh I understand now. I can always print to the console from within my function, rather than outside of it on every call.  Plus I didn't know about join.  Thank you Jack for the lesson on this!

Comment: No problem @klewis, always glad to help.